# The WebGL 3D Animation is stopped when scrolling down the page

Tags: javascript, html

I added a WebGL 3D animation to the page with VantaJS.org, I have completely written the code as same as the official example, but the 3D animation is stopped once I scroll down the page. You can check the demo here: https://lovage.io/3d and my codes below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>3D</title>
    <script src="https://lovage.io/3d/js/three.r92.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://lovage.io/3d/js/vanta.wave.min.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>
 <section id="layer"></section>
 <div style="height:3000px;"></div>

 <script>
  VANTA.WAVES({
        el: "#layer",
  });
 </script> 
  </body>
  
</html>
```

However, the official demos works fine on my browser. Anyone can give me any tips debugging?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've seen you have opened an issue on the repo about it, checkout this *forceAnimate* option: https://github.com/tengbao/vanta/issues/22#issuecomment-536245655

Comment: forceAnimate option fixes my issue! That issue is not opened by me, I haven't found this issue on the repo, but it's useful!

Comment: Glad to hear you've solved!. So this is issuer is not you ? https://github.com/tengbao/vanta/issues/45

Answer (score -1):

You need to give height and width to your section.
You attached the event on that tag but since has no dimensions you lost the animation at the first scroll.

Try this

```
body, section{
   height: 100%; width: 100%
}
```